# How to export or import data from DB Schema using Flyway

Tags: database, jenkins, flyway

Can some one please explain how to configure flyway to export or import DB Schema through Jenkins. Currently I have FlyWay Community edition configured in my jenkins.

Comment: I do not think flyway is the tool for any data job, its more to do with schema and reference data, not for transactional data which is mainly the scope of export and import.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We have a procedure to do export. But I need to run it by executing it. Is there any scope to do that from flyway.

Comment: Flyway repeatable migration may help. https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/repeatable this is run after every migration when there is an update on this migration. Usually for creating/updating procedures, triggers and functions. But gut feel is that export/ import should be managed outside of flyway

Comment: which DB are You referring to?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use DB specific tools, for example in Oracle - `DBMS_DATAPUMP` (but never tried export/import this way), or in Postgresql `pg_dump`, `pg_restore`, according to [How to use flyway to migrate data from one DB to another DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602306/how-to-use-flyway-to-migrate-data-from-one-db-to-another-db)

You can try a Java migration for this.