# How to use flyway to migrate data from one DB to another DB?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-migration, flyway

I have two postgreSql DB on different server lets say A and B.
Can I use flyway some how to copy all data from DB A to B which is newly setup and empty.
Its will be helpful if anyone point me to correct direction and tool, requirement is to copy data from one DB to another through some tool automation huge data volume need to consider in solution.

Comment: Don't use something slow and complicated to copy a large database. Use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`.

Comment: [pg_basebackup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgbasebackup.html) if you want to copy the whole PostgreSQL cluster, not just some single DB.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks , migrate  word used in flyway some how confusing for me, I understand now its involved manual script generation and need to feed to flyway for migration and no direct solution.

Answer (score 6):

Flyway doesn't directly support such a capability. However, you could do the following:

- As Laurenz says, use [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgdump.html) to extract DB A into a script file
- Create a Flyway migration script and copy in the contents of the script file
- Run the [Migrate](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/) command against DB B

Comment: Sometimes this couldn't be an option as it's requires service downtime.